# Assigning one 2D array to another

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

So in my program I have a function which passes into it a 2D array and I want to set another 2D array equal to that 2D array. I am coding this in C++ and can't quite get the syntax right. Right now I have the following:

```
void MyFunction(float **two_d_array){
    float newArray[4][4];
    //Set new array equal to two_d_array
}
```

two_d_array will also always be 4x4 so the dimensions themselves aren't an issue.

Comment: What is the problem? Do you have an error? If yes, what is the error message? Or should we guess?

Answer (score 6):

I hope you are not passing a two-dimensional array as a double pointer to your function.

Anyways, you can just write

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)
        newArray[i][j] = two_d_array[i][j];
```

If you have another two-dimensional array (and **not** an array of pointers), then simply use `memcpy()`:

```
void foo(float arr[][4])
{
    float newArray[4][4];
    memcpy(newArray, arr, sizeof(newArray));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. But what is wrong with passing it as a double pointer? The syntax for accessing elements will be the same, no?

Comment: @user1855952 The syntax will, just the semantics won't. Arrays are not pointers, pointers are not arrays, and two-dimensional arrays don't decay into double pointers but into a pointer to an array with the size of the second dimension.

Comment: As we're in C++ I's suggest passing array by reference to avoid losing the extent information. `typedef double d4x4[4][4]; void foo(d4x4& arr)`. Can save your life preventing to pass in a double[1][4].

Comment: @BalogPal As we're in C++, you can entirely avoid arrays at all and just use an `std::vector<std::vector<float> >` instead.

Comment: @H2CO3: guess you really meant std::array, vector would be a different beast on too many fronts. array is a good replacement, but you must do it all the way, if the existing code already uses C-style arrays adding new function better leave it alone. But taking ref makes it little more roboust.

Answer (score 1):

When you define a two dimentional array as

```
float a[4][4]
```

Its type is float [4][4].

if you want to pass float** to the function you can create your with float**

```
float** f = (float**) malloc(sizeof(float *)*4);
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
      f[i] = (float*) malloc(sizeof(float)*4);
    }
//initialize
MyFunction(f);
```

And Myfunction will be similar

```
void MyFunction(float **two_d_array){
    float newArray[4][4];
    for(int i=0;i<4;i++){
        float* one_d = & two_d_array[i][0];
        for(int j=0;j<4;j++){
            newArray[i][j] = one_d[j];
        }   
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you must assign the second dimenson, and the first dimension passing by a integer parameter, it will look like this:
void foo(float arr[][4], int dim);